# Too few arguments to function drush_migrate_tools_migrate_messages()

Tags: drush, migrations

I'm in the middle of a D7->D8 migration and tried running the command `drush migrate-messages` but got the following error:

```
ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function drush_migrate_tools_migrate_messages(), 
0 passed in /mysite/vendor/drush/drush/includes/command.inc on line 422 and exactly 1 
expected in drush_migrate_tools_migrate_messages()
```

but I've never had this error before running the same command and can't find anything in [the documentation](https://drushcommands.com/drush-8x/migrate/migrate-messages/) about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **Examples** section makes it pretty clear. `drush migrate-messages` expects one parameter, the machine name of your migration for it to display the migration messages. There's no "show all" option. Run [`drush migrate-status`](https://drushcommands.com/drush-8x/migrate/migrate-status/) to see all migration machine names (left column) available.

Comment: Thanks. Your answer worked for a while, then stopped: https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate_tools/issues/2940847